# Opening List View of a child or grand child for the specific Account from which it is accessed for mass update

Tags: list-view

The use case is to allow the user to select records presented in a list view so that the user could take some mass action on the selected records.

The data model is Accounts -> Sites -> Assets

For example, if the user is on the detail page of ABC Inc., on clicking a button the user will be taken to the list view page of Assets object where only the assets of ABC Inc are presented to the user. The user can then select few records for a specific mass action.

Will it be possible to get to the list view of the Assets from the Account detail view?

I am trying to leverage the standard list view for mass action instead of using a Visualforce page.

If I have to use a Visualforce page, how would it be done?

Thanks in advance.

Newbie

Update: I have been researching this on the web. It appears as if the standard list view cannot be filtered unless the filter is created. In that case, this filter will have to be updated from every account. Am I correct in my inference?

On the Visualforce side, I came across the post on Wrapper Class that allows checkbox to be added to the list for selection. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class
I have developed the Visualforce page, created the query and added 'Select all' 'Unselect all' buttons. Not I just need to pass the Account Id to the Visualforce page so that I can populate the where clause of the SOQL.

Please let me know that this is how it should be done as I want to make sure that the solution is optimal. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issues with this?